# Save image file with php?

Tags: php, image

I have this code in my root to auto save image file when user click on link

```
<?
// Force download of image file specified in URL query string and which
// is in the same directory as this script:
if(!empty($_GET['file']))
{
  $filename = $_GET['file']; // don't accept other directories
  $size = @getimagesize($filename);
  $fp = @fopen($filename, "rb");
  if ($size && $fp)
  {
    header("Content-type: {$size['mime']}");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'); 
    fpassthru($fp);
    exit;
  }
}
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
```

**Questions**:

1. Can hackers send any string to this file and save my root files? (example: index.php or etc...)
2. How I can check URL contain image file?

Comment: Are all the files in the same directory? It would be best practice to have all the public images in one folder and lock your script to that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of thing where you need a whitelist approach. If all your images are stored in the same folder, just pass the file name (e.g. `image.jpg`) without any paths and disallow the occurrence of any `/`.

The check with [`is_scalar()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.is-scalar.php) below checks that someone doesn't do `?file[]=test`, which will send an array to the server. This isn't a big deal sometimes but it can make the server output errors that we don't want.

```
if (!empty($_GET['file']) && is_scalar($_GET['file'])) {
    $filename = $_GET['file'];
    if (strpos('/', $filename) !== false) {
        exit;
    }
```

We can then look at the file extension and determine whether it is allowed or not. Notice the use of [`strtolower()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) so it matches uppercase extensions (`PNG`, `JPG`, etc.). The check `$ext != $filename` makes sure that no one is just passing "jpg" or "png" as file name.

```
    $allowed_types = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');
    $ext = preg_replace('/^(.*\.)(.*?)$/', '\\2', $filename);
    if (!in_array(strtolower($ext), $allowed_types) && $ext != $filename) {
        exit;
    }
```

Finally, check that the file actually exists and that it is indeed a file. [`file_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) also matches directories, so we're being extra sure by check with `is_file()` as well.

```
    $filename = '/images/' . $filename;
    if (!file_exists($filename) || !is_file($filename)) {
        exit;
    }
```

After these checks, you are sure that `$filename` is OK and you can start doing things like the following (taken from your code):

```
$size = @getimagesize($filename);
```

Answer (score 2):

Q1: You should restrict access to only specific directories - if that is just 1 directory then there is no need for you to use the directory provided from the `$_GET` request, simply include it in your php instead.

```
$filename = end( explode( '/', $_GET['file'] ) );
$filename = '/uploadsdirectory/' . $filename;
```

Q2: To check the extension of the file being requested you should do:

```
$extension = end( explode( '.', $filename ) );
```

this will return `jpg` or `png` etc.. bascially whatever is after the final period

Comment: if i put this file in result directory and then link to it; is there any problem?

Comment: as long as you check it's an image file, you'll be ok

Answer (score 2):

use [exif_imagetype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)

```
int exif_imagetype ( string $filename )
```